# How to pass unicode keywords to **kwargs

Tags: python, unicode, keyword-argument

I was exception the following to work.

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    print kwargs
foo(**{'a':'b'})
foo(**{u'a':'b'})
```

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "", line 1, in 
> >     TypeError: m() keywords must be strings

Am I doing something wrong or I should I fix it?

Comment: `foo() argument after ** must be a mapping, not set`. I think you meant `'a':'b'`. What's your platform? python-2.7-8.fc14.1.x86_64 works fine with that fix.

Comment: This runs quite happily for me in Python 2.7.1

Comment: I fixed the error in the question. But the problem remains, I am running 2.6 and it crashes.

Comment: you're running 2.6.1 (revision 67515), issue 2646 was fixed in revision 68805. So, again: update your python 2.6 to the latest version (2.6.6 as of today).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Upgrade to Python 2.6.5 or later.

Comment: Yes.  This was fixed for 2.6.  More info: http://bugs.python.org/issue2646 and http://bugs.python.org/issue4978.

Comment: @mipadi It seems fairly safe to assume that the examples were supposed to be dicts instead of set literals, since the exception given only makes sense in that case.  And the exception would only happen pre-2.6.

Comment: I am running 2.6 (Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49))

Comment: I'm reluctant upvoting the answer. It should at least have @WillMcCutchen's comment integrated.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading wasn't an option for me so I'm calling this on dicts as needed--

```
def flatten_unicode_keys(d):
    for k in d:
        if isinstance(k, unicode):
            v = d[k]
            del d[k]
            d[str(k)] = v
```

Comment: I think a simple workaround like this is more valuable than the accepted answer.